# Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! CentOS

Tags: java, xml, ant, red5, centos6

I want to Configure Streaming Server in CentOS 6.5
I'm Using **Ant**
After installing the java packages and also the ant version required . So when i type ant prepare to prepare my ant server it show me this error :

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
```

Build failed and I am sure of all steps before this . Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check This [CentOs Org Forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21745)
It Can Help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
android update project --target 5 --path /path/to/android/project
```